# import the variable from ".py" to ".html" for jinja

Tags: html, python-3.x, variables, jinja2

I am trying to **display the variable `__version__` from the file `__init__.py` on my web page `spawn.html` with jinja2**   .

The problem is that I can not find the call of the method `render_template()`, where I can put my variable.

So, **is there any easy and nice way to display the variable with jinja2**?

Comment: What do you mean by "i cannot find call of the method render_template()"? - Do you mean you cannot call that method for some reason? Can you post your jinja2 python code?

Comment: The project isn't small , if you want i can give the reference. But i don't want to solve this problem by modifying  render_template() (finding calling of this method is another problem). So, problem doesn't depend on the code.

Comment: Another reason, why i don't want to do through `render_template(__variable__=__variable__)` is that i have many other html files that extends this html file and i don't want to modify all render_templates() in all handlers

Comment: @AMagoon       i cannot find a calling of the method in the project, so i cannot find the place where this page is rendered

Comment: I can't think of anyway to get a dynamic variable into an HTML template without using the built-in methods provided. If the issue is that you simply can't find where `render_template()` is called, try finding a file called `views.py`. If you find it do a search (Ctrl-F) for `"spawn.html"`. That should locate the correct function to pass your `__version__` variable to.

If you still have an issue with the files that extend `spawn.html` then maybe some javascript is necessary to hide the `__version__` variable on all URLs except `../spawn.html`

Comment: Write the version value to a separate file and include that file from html template.

Comment: @VPfB yeah , but i wanted to do it with __init__.py (there are several strings with code)

Comment: @igor you CAN write a file from any .py file

Comment: @VPfB i mean when i include file with code to html template can i choose only one string or better only value of some variable ?

Comment: @igor I'm sorry, I do not know details of your application to answer your last comment. My suggestion was to write few lines of python code that creates a html fragment file with contents you need. Then you can include it in any HTML document using Jinja2 `{% include "version.html" %}` or similar

Comment: @VPfB no problem., anyway  thank you for the  advices.